# Bash script TAR by Filetype is not gzipping the specified filetypes on recursive command

Tags: bash, find, tar, xargs, xbmc

Simply put, I did an exhaustive library update on my network to be compatible with XBMC. Now that it's done, I thought it wouldn't hurt to periodically make a backup of the nfo,bub,srt,jpg,tbn files (everything except any video file) that are in the various directories and subdirectories in my TV Shows folder. I also wanted to zip it by date. After playing around, I got this to semi-work:

```
find '/volume2/MyMedia/TV Shows/' -type f \( -name \*\.sub -o -name \*\.srt -o -name \*\.nfo -o -name \*\.jpg -o -name \*\.tbn \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar -pvczf '/volume2/Backups/XBMC Backups/'XBMC-TVShows-NFO-JPG-TBN-SUB-Backup-$(date +%m-%d-%y).tar.gz
```

It goes through the motions (scanning every directory and finding the files), and I see the zip file grow, but then suddenly the tar.gz goes down to 0 bytes and counts up again. I think it's doing that once it hits a new directory to scan.

At the end, I get a 1.8MB file with only the last directory it scanned through. Inside that, is *almost* everything, except it omitted 1 of the subdirectories. IE: It zipped up '30 Rock' and all of the files I specified, but, it did that for all folders except Season 2.

So I am at a loss. Everything looks clear to me in the code. For some reason it's not running properly. I think I have tunnel vision on the project now. A fresh set of eyes would be magnificent!

Here is an output: http://pastebin.com/ywctQ5Sf

Here is what the final tar.gz contained: http://s23.postimg.org/6pc22h7yz/output.png

Final note: The directories of the shows that it backs up do have whitespaces in them. So there is a directory structure like so:

```
>volume2
->MyMedia
-->TV Shows
--->Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood
---->Season 1
----->Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood.S01E01.Fullmetal Alchemist.nfo
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `xargs` splits the huge list of files across *multiple* `tar` commands, which each try to create a new file. Try using the `-A` option instead of `-vczf ...` and pipe the whole command to `gzip`:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 tar -A | gzip - > "....tar.gz"
```

Comment: I tried: `find '/volume2/MyMedia/TV Shows/' -type f \( -name \*\.sub -o -name \*\.srt -o -name \*\.nfo
-o -name \*\.jpg -o -name \*\.tbn \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar -A '/volume1/Backups/Critical Backup
s/XBMC Backups/'XBMC-TVSeries-NFO-JPG-TBN-SUB-Backup-$(date +%m-%d-%y).tar.gz` and also tried with a lowercase 'a' and neither changed the outcome. In fact, it didn't work. Clearly I am missing something. I apologize if I sound dense. I'm still learning and trying my hardest :)

Comment: @Jacob Please re-read the advice you were given, particularly the last sentence.

Comment: So I tried it out, and I keep getting hit with `tar: invalid option -- A`.

Comment: Please check `man tar` to see if your `tar` has some option to add files to an existing archive. It could be that your version simply has other options.

Comment: Thank you for your help l0b0. I think that my Synology (running BusyBox 1.16.1) is simply less robust. I will most likely need to bootstrap it, or use a Windows bat file. Your coding works I'm sure. I simply don't have the proper version of tar to do it.

Answer (score 0):

So after revisiting this, I tried l0b0's method. It comes back with:

```
tar: Options `-Aru' are incompatible with `-f -'
```

So I looked into another way and came up with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /volume1/Media/TV\ Series/ -iname "*.sub" -exec tar rvfP /volume1/Backups/TestBackup.tar {} \;
find /volume1/Media/TV\ Series/ -iname "*.srt" -exec tar rvfP /volume1/Backups/TestBackup.tar {} \;
find /volume1/Media/TV\ Series/ -iname "*.nfo" -exec tar rvfP /volume1/Backups/TestBackup.tar {} \;
find /volume1/Media/TV\ Series/ -iname "*.jpg" -exec tar rvfP /volume1/Backups/TestBackup.tar {} \;
find /volume1/Media/TV\ Series/ -iname "*.tbn" -exec tar rvfP /volume1/Backups/TestBackup.tar {} \;
gzip /volume1/Backups/TestBackup.tar
```

It takes a long time, but I let it run in the middle of the night when nothing else is going on, and it works. I only need to run this backup very infrequently anyway.

If you were so inclined, you can also add an elapsed timer:

```
#!/bin/bash
date1=$(date +"%s")
# Script stuff here. Uncommented...
date2=$(date +"%s")
diff=$(($date2-$date1))
echo "$(($diff / 60)) minutes and $(($diff % 60)) seconds elapsed."
```